# setting up a linux pyinstaller bundle for a wxpython+matplotlib application

Tags: pyinstaller

I wrote a small application to test how `pyinstaller` behaves when used to set up a linux bundle of an application depending on `wxpython` and `matplotlib`.
The first call to `pyinstaller` generated the `spec` file that I further tuned to complete the bundle. However, when running the generated bundle I run into troubles.

Indeed, the application starts (e.g. a basic `matplotlib` plot embedded with i `wxpython` frame) but I get a the following warnings and errors:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(app:4383): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(app:4383): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

...
...
...

(app:4383): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(app:4383): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(app:4383): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(app:4383): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'dialog-question' for stock: Unrecognized image file format
```

Those warnings disappear when the *app.py* script is run using my local `python`.

Moreover, when quiting the bundled application, I get a `wxpython` dialog box without the proper question mark icon (see *quit_bad.png* below) in the dialog. Everything is OK when I run the the *app.py* script
with my local `python` (see *quit_good.png* below). I am pretty sure that this second problem is somewhat related to the first one. Up to now, I could not find a way to solve this. I followed some posts that indicates
how to solve the warnings problem by installing `gtk` related themes but that does not help, which is normal in some way in the sense that it seems to be a
problem specific to how my app behaves when bundled - all these troubles disappearing when the application is run with my local `python`.

Here are my settings:

- ubuntu trusty
- python 2.7.6
- wxpython 2.8.12.1
- matplotlib 1.3.1
- pyinstaller 3.2

And here are my *app.py* and *app.spec* files:

**app.py**:

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('gtkagg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def draw(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        panel.draw()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_quit)

    def on_quit(self, event=None):

        d = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Do you really want to quit ?', 'Question', wx.YES_NO|wx.YES_DEFAULT|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        if d.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
            self.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    fr = MyFrame(None, title='test')
    fr.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**app.spec**:

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=['.'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['_wxagg','_tkagg'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='app')
```

Would you have any idea how to solve this ? Thanks a lot

[image: wxpython - bad]

[image: wxpython - good]

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue, did you manage to get anywhere on this?  Thanks!